# Multiple Server Managing Admin

Tags: remote-access, network-administration, sysadmin

What can I use to manage my remote Linux based servers at remote locations, like mass deployment, I want to be able to install applications via apt-get or similar, but have it install on all, given the right addressing to each server?

Comment: Not using any of those yself, but take a look at [Puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)) and similiar [configuration management software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software) while waiting for good recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

[Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) is probably the easiest to start with configuration management system [because](https://www.ansible.com/overview/it-automation) it doesn't need a server or any special software on the managed hosts.